# Encoding differences from active record to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding, character-encoding

The special characters that come from the server are not rendered right, but the ones in static text in the html are rendered ok.

I have a Record in my dev base. It's title is 'Légende'.

```
[1] pry(main)> Record.last.title
  Record Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "records".* FROM "records"  ORDER BY "records"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> "Légende"
[2] pry(main)> Record.last.title.encoding
  Record Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "records".* FROM "records"  ORDER BY "records"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

When i want to #show it in my view, it prints `Le‘gende`. It's not the usual encoding problem, because it doesn't print `&eacute;` or `Ã©`.

Plus, if i copy and paste `Le‘gende` from the web page, it becomes `Légende` again. It's weird.

records#show

```
  def show
    @record = Record.find(params[:id])
  end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1>Bibliothèque</h1>
<h2><%= @record.title %></h2>
```

config/application.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

layout/application.html.erb

```
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # encoding: utf-8

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a font problem.

For future reference : the culprit is open sans.